# Load registered external assembly (dll) in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, com

I'm trying to load a Citrix Receiver's COM dll into Powershell session. I've registered the dll (wfica.ocx) using regsvr32. The assemblies was registered and I checked referencing registered assembly in Visual Studio with C#. It works, but when try in Powershell using

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Citrix.ICAClient")
```

or

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Citrix.ICAClient"
```

it can't find the specified assembly.

I've tried also with full path of assembly

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\WfIcaLib.dll"
```

and it works, but I cannot use the classes properly because of Embedded Interop Type Flag (I don't know and I didn't find an answer for this for Powershell). I prefer first solution because I don't want to hardcode full paths in my script (the script will be deployed on a large scale and, in my opinion, this will not be scalable).

EDIT: I've also tried using "using namespace" statement from Powershell 5, but no success.

How can I load the registered COM dlls into Powershell without hardcoded or another code to find the assembly?

EDIT: How can I run the COM 32 bit code from Powershell 64bit host in a scalable solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to use/treat a COM dll like a .net assembly.

You don't say what you're trying to do, once you've successfully loaded the assembly, but try using [this script](http://www.florisvanderploeg.com/ica-connections-using-powershell-part-1/), from Floris Van Der Ploeg's site as a starting point:

```
#http://www.florisvanderploeg.com/ica-connections-using-powershell-part-1/
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\WfIcaLib.dll")
$ICA = New-Object WFICALib.ICAClientClass
$ICA.Address = "XASRV001"
$ICA.Application = ""
$ICA.Username = "TestUser01"
$ICA.SetProp("Password","MyUsersPassword")
$ICA.Domain = "LAB"
$ICA.Launch = $true
$ICA.OutputMode = [WFICALib.OutputMode]::OutputModeNormal
$ICA.Connect()
```

Google is a useful tool ;)

Comment: As I mentioned, I've tried loading the assembly file, but it doesn't work because of matter of registered classes or something related to this: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {238F6F83-B8B4-11CF-8771-00A024541EE3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))." ...

Comment: Can you post the message you get when you run the load file? Do the first two lines of code work?

Comment: I've tried also using tlbimp.exe to make a callable wrapper for COM, same error.

Comment: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {238F6F83-B8B4-11CF-8771-00A024541EE3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."
At line:2 char:8
+ $ICA = New-Object WficaLib.ICAClientClass
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: I've tried with Powershell_ISE (x86) and it seems to work...but why a 64 bit host application can't load a 32 bit COM object?

Comment: Because these are two different architectures.

Comment: Of course, but as Operating System can run 32 bit code, a 64bit host application should run 32bit, everything can be done in programming..

Comment: Windows OS uses a very complicated *thunking* layer but it works only per the entire process, meaning you'd have to implement the thunking yourself to mix the architectures inside one process. Not sure it's even possible.